# Showing asyncronsly data in a carousel with Angular 4

Tags: html, angular, firebase

I have an HTML template with an Images Carousel.  I just adapted that template in Angular 4 and works perfectly. Now, I'm trying to get content from a Firebase Database, but the carousel breakes by the asyncronsly retrieving data.

The results of query stores to a variable called `data` as a `FirebaseListObservable`. Then I'm using `*ngFor="let item in data | async"` to get image of each item. And it shows perfectly but breaking the carousel style.

How can I make DOM elements charged only when all data has retrieved?

I tried with `*ngIf="data"` as I did before, with AngularJS, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you just use `*ngIf="data"`, it will always return true so your carousel will not wait for that.

Try to use this `*ngIf="data | async)?.length"`. I'm just guessing here since you didn't provide your carousel code.

Hope this helps.